# Add Multiple email Address in Reply-to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email

In Already build project management system software. I like to Add some more feature. In my Application there is a functionality of messages means one user can sent message to his client or another user that message receiver can see his dashboard and he also receive that message to his mail inbox

so that i create code that send that message to both my email address and that users email address

but the problem is that when receiver reply to that mail message only went to only one email address that i put in reply-to

So how can i put more than one email address in php mail or any other way to send reply mail to multiple email address

here is my code for send mails

```
function send_notification($sender, $receiver, $super, $email, $subject, $text ) {
    $instance =& get_instance();
    $instance->load->helper('file');
    $instance->load->library('parser');

    $data["core_settings"] = Setting::first(array('conditions' => array('admin_id = ?', $super)));

    $instance->email->from($data["core_settings"]->email, $data["core_settings"]->company);

    $instance->email->reply_to("def@example.com", "mnp", "abc@example.com", "ABC DEF");

            $instance->email->to($email); 
            $instance->email->subject($subject); 
            //Set parse values
            $parse_data = array(
                                'company' => $data["core_settings"]->company,
                                'link' => base_url(),
                                'logo' => '<img src="'.base_url().''.$data["core_settings"]->logo.'" alt="'.$data["core_settings"]->company.'"/>',
                                'invoice_logo' => '<img src="'.base_url().''.$data["core_settings"]->invoice_logo.'" alt="'.$data["core_settings"]->company.'"/>',
                                'message' => $text
                                );
            $email_invoice = read_file('./application/views/'.$data["core_settings"]->template.'/templates/email_notification.html');
            $message = $instance->parser->parse_string($email_invoice, $parse_data);
            $instance->email->message($message);
            $instance->email->send();

}
```

Comment: Maybe try using loop? Addres will be in array and you can read this using for each or different loop.

Comment: Ya I tried loop but it's not working fine can you explain it in details

Answer (score 1):

Make a for loop that goes trough all your email addresses. You can put your email addresses in a database or array what ever you prefer.

Using an array:

```
$emailAdresses = array("example@mail.com", "example2@mail.com");
foreach ($emailAdresses as $i) {
  mail($emailAdresses[$i],"","");
}
```

Comment: my programme is written in codeigniter (object oriented programming)

Comment: I don't know what the problem is? You can make a get method for the emailAdresses and run this in a method from an another class.

Comment: You have to change the reply_to method in order to send the mail to multiple email adresses. Another approach is to make a for loop in your main program that send an email to every user with the $instance->email->reply_to("def@example.com", "mnp", "abc@example.com", "ABC DEF"); line instead of my mail("","","") line.

Comment: ya but when i put multiple multiple email address in cc or bcc it replies on only one email address in which is in from not all the email address in cc or bcc

Answer (score 0):

**You can try some thing like this**

```
$list = array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com');
$instance->email->reply_to($list, 'Your Name');
```

**OR**

```
$instance->email->reply_to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com', 'Your Name');
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: my programme is written in codeigniter (object oriented programming)

Comment: ok, so can you please add some code detail in your question what you have tried! so that I can check that in more clearly.

Comment: @user3604115 now I have updated my answer so please check this.

Comment: I tried both bot not working in first option it takes "My Name" <Array@p3plcpnl0052.prod.phx3.secureserver.net> as reply to And in second option it takes "my name" <one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com> as reply to